# How to make almost sorted list of 2**20 elements in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

N=2**20
We build the list so that A[i+1] = A[i] + random_value *between* [1, 5]
then we move N//20 elements to random place

My code so far:

```
import random

N = pow(2, 20)

almostSortedArray = list(range(N))

elementsToShuffle = random.sample(range(N), k=N//20)
for i in elementsToShuffle:
    j = random.choice([x for x in range(len(almostSortedArray)) if x not in elementsToShuffle])
    almostSortedArray[i], almostSortedArray[j] = almostSortedArray[j], almostSortedArray[i]
```

It iterates very slowly... and no solution comes up. How to solve this?

Comment: Is it okay to use NumPy here? For any list/array that size, NumPy is likely the far better option.

Comment: Sure! any solution that solves this problem

Comment: Your problem is this:  `[x for x in range(len(almostSortedArray)) if x not in elementsToShuffle]`  This is inside your loop, so it's going to result in slow code.  Also, isn't `len(almostSortedArray)` just `N`?

Comment: "we move N//20 elements to random place": can that also include switch the places of N//20 elements? That is, they are randomly picked, and move to each other places.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to write `2**20` and not `2^20`. The `**` operator means power in python, but the `^` operator means bitwise-xor. As such, `2^20 == 0b00010 ^ 0b10100 == 0b10101 == 22 != 2**20`

Comment: Yes, it also includes switch of places @9769953

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, then this can work with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

N = 2**20

# Seed the random number generator
rng = default_rng()

diff = rng.integers(1, 6, size=N)
# Create an array with elements differing 1-5 for each next element
a = np.cumsum(diff)
# Create a set of random, but unique, indices
indices = rng.choice(np.arange(N), size=N//20, replace=False)
# Grab the corresponding values
values = a[indices]
# Shuffle the indices
rng.shuffle(indices)
# And set the values back into a, with the shuffled indices
a[indices] = values
```

For reference, on my six-year old Macbook, that took about 25 milliseconds.

Calling

```
a_sorted = np.sort(a)
```

takes about 20 milliseconds.

Comment: 6 microseconds including the line `import numpy as np`?

Comment: @Stef Yes, but I ran it a few times in notebook using `%time`, so the import is already there and is thus likely not included in this timing.

Comment: Moreover, the sum of the original array, and the sum of shuffled array, are not equal. But only for larger values of N.

Comment: @KellyBundy Found it: `%time` is not `%%time` (and I knew that; just overlooked it). Thanks for keeping me on my toes. Timings edited in the answer.

Comment: That seems to be the case. Since there is no unique option to `rng.integers()`, I went with `rng.choice` and `replace=False`).

Comment: Avoiding duplicates made it 10 times faster? That seems suspicious again :-)

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ . Perhaps I read the timings incorrectly the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the pool for the j-choices only once, and use sets for it. Then it's linear time instead of cubic.

```
import random

N = 2 ** 20

almostSortedArray = list(range(N))

elementsToShuffle = random.sample(range(N), k=N//20)
others = list(set(range(N)) - set(elementsToShuffle))

for i in elementsToShuffle:
    j = random.choice(others)
    almostSortedArray[i], almostSortedArray[j] = almostSortedArray[j], almostSortedArray[i]
```